# sysdate() causes Postgres to do ignore the Index and do a costly Sequential Scan

Tags: oracle, postgresql, enterprisedb

Anyone ever encounter this? **Postgres Enterprise DB Advanced Server 11.5.12**

`sysdate()` (Oracle proprietary) results in a Seq Scan of, in this case, 4,782 rows:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT p.id, p.practice
 FROM PatientStatistics ps
 INNER JOIN Patients p
   ON p.id=ps.patient
 WHERE ps.nextfutureapptdateservertime <= sysdate()
 ORDER BY p.id ASC;

Hash Join  (cost=799.81..1761.53 rows=4782 width=8)
   Hash Cond: (p.id = ps.patient)
   ->  Index Only Scan using patients_index3 on patients p  (cost=0.29..921.44 rows=15442 width=8)
   ->  Hash  (cost=644.11..644.11 rows=4782 width=4)
         ->  Seq Scan on patientstatistics ps  (cost=0.00..644.11 rows=4782 width=4)
               Filter: (nextfutureapptdateservertime <= sysdate)
```

Changing to `now()` or `current_timestamp` (SQL Standard) fixes the issue. Postgres is correctly using the Index:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT p.id, p.practice
FROM PatientStatistics ps
INNER JOIN Patients p
   ON p.id=ps.patient
WHERE ps.nextfutureapptdateservertime <= now()
ORDER BY p.id ASC;

Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..51.41 rows=17 width=8)
   ->  Index Only Scan using "patientstatisti_idx$$_0c9a0048" on patientstatistics ps  (cost=0.29..8.53 rows=17 width=4)
         Index Cond: (nextfutureapptdateservertime <= now())
   ->  Index Scan using patients_pk on patients p  (cost=0.29..2.52 rows=1 width=8)
         Index Cond: (id = ps.patient)
```

Interesting to note the different in output of those functions:

```
SELECT now();
SELECT current_timestamp;

15-JAN-20 09:36:41.932741 -05:00
15-JAN-20 09:36:41.932930 -05:00

SELECT sysdate();

15-JAN-20 09:37:17
```

Perhaps Postgres's Date Indexes are hashed using Datetimes that have Decimal portion. The planner sees it was passed a date that doesn't have Decimal, and it knows the Index's Keys won't line up accurately, so it backs off to a Scan to ensure the query delivers 100% accurate results.

I could find nothing about this online after a 30-minute Googling.

Comment: What is the stability of sysdate()?  current_timestamp and now() (they are the same) are stable because they do not change within a transaction.  Is sysdate() the same?

Comment: As you are using Enterprise Advanced Server you should have support contract with them - I would file that as a bug there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know EDB's proprietary fork, so the following is based on guesswork.

`now()` or (equivalently) `current_timestamp` is a `STABLE` function, so it returns the same value if it is evaluated more than once in the course of a statement execution (and indeed of a transaction).

The suspicion is that `sysdate`, like PostgreSQL's `clock_timestamp()`, is `VOLATILE` (returns the actual time).

Then the function can have a different value every time it is compared to a row, which makes it impossible to use an index scan.

If my suspicion is not correct, I'd call it an EDB bug.

Comment: Even when tagged `volatile`, my DIY function results in an index scan.

Comment: @wildplasser Is it an SQL function that gets inlined?

Comment: with `clock_timestamp()` I do get the undesired behaviour, as expected.

Comment: Exactly. Your DIY function is **not** `VOLATILE`.

Comment: No, but the volatility does **not** affect `now()` [probably because it is inlined sql]

Comment: I don't get you - `now()` is stable, **not** volatile.

Comment: Probably, `now()` retains its STABLE attribute, even if it is wrapped in a VOLATILE function like mine. (seems logical to me)

Comment: As I said above, if the function is inlined, the situatuon changes, because then the query actually contains `now()`. Use `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE])` to verufy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know *how* they implemented it, but this workaround functions correctly here:

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mysysdate(OUT timestamptz)
AS
$func$
select now();
$func$
language sql stable;

select mysysdate() ;

EXPLAIN select *
FROM public.feature_timeslice
WHERE valid_time_begin < mysysdate() - '10 year + 14 days'::interval;

select version() ;
\df+ mysysdate
```

---

Output:

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION
           mysysdate           
-------------------------------
 2020-01-15 17:15:13.896497+01
(1 row)

                                              QUERY PLAN                                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using feature_timeslice_alt2 on feature_timeslice  (cost=0.42..4474.84 rows=9206 width=28)
   Index Cond: (valid_time_begin < (now() - '10 years 14 days'::interval))
(2 rows)

                                                version                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4, 64-bit
(1 row)

                                                                                       List of functions
 Schema |   Name    |     Result data type     |     Argument data types      | Type | Volatility | Parallel |  Owner   | Security | Access privileges | Language |  Source code  | Description 
--------+-----------+--------------------------+------------------------------+------+------------+----------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+---------------+-------------
 tmp    | mysysdate | timestamp with time zone | OUT timestamp with time zone | func | stable     | unsafe   | postgres | invoker  |                   | sql      |              +| 
        |           |                          |                              |      |            |          |          |          |                   |          | select now();+| 
        |           |                          |                              |      |            |          |          |          |                   |          |               | 
(1 row)
```

---

Note: the granularity does not affect the query plan,

```
select date_trunc('sec', now());
```

also results in an indexscan.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. It must be the Volatility thing. PG's docs on the matter. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/xfunc-volatility.html

They show "timeofday()" as an example of Volatile.

- **now()** - `STABLE` - Time when this query began. Call it 6 times in the same query, it returns the same time.
- **timeofday() and sysdate()** - `VOLATILE` - Time at the moment that time function() was called; not the query. It's like shelling out to the Operating System's `date` tool. Call it 6 times in the same query, you'll get 6 different times.